# ¿Por qué al ingresar sesión obtengo ROLE_ANONYMOUS?

Tags: java, spring-boot, autenticación, spring-security

### Estoy lidiando con un error de autenticación en mi aplicación que utiliza Spring Security 5.7.6

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Spring Boot en su versión 2.7.8 con Spring Security y estoy lidiando con un error que no estoy encontrando su origen. La seguridad de la aplicación está basada en una autenticación por formulario (Form Login), por lo tanto toma los parametros de "username" y "password" para validar el usuario y generar una cookie de sesión.
El problema se encuentra al momento de intentar ingresar a la aplicación introduciendo el usuario y su contraseña, obtengo un error. Realizando un debug de la aplicación me doy cuenta que el usuario nunca se autentica con las autoridades que debería, en este caso, autoridad "ADMIN" o "OPERATOR", sino que lo hace con una autoridad "ROLE_ANONYMOUS". Investigando con lo que pude, entiendo que se trata de un rol que asigna Spring por defecto para aquellos usuarios que no poseen una autoridad definida, sin embargo, claramente esta no es la intención que tengo sobre la aplicación, ya que todos los usuarios que deseen usarla, deben estar autenticados y poseer uno de los roles mencionados anteriormente. A continuación, les expongo las clases de configuración de Spring Security.

*WebAuthentication.class*

```
@Configuration
public class WebAuthentication extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(username -> {
            com.orbita.akerf.models.User user = userDAO.findByUsername(username);

            if (user != null) {
                return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(user.getRole().name()));
            } else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Unknown user: " + username);
            }
        });
    }
```

*WebAuthorization.class*

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebAuthorization{

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .antMatchers("/static/**", "/assets/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/")
                        .permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v1/auth/users")
                        .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v1/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/v1/**/op/**", "/v1/**/op")
                        .hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "OPERATOR")
                        .antMatchers("/v1/**")
                        .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
        http
                .formLogin(login -> {
                            try {
                                login
                                        .usernameParameter("username")
                                        .passwordParameter("password")
                                        .loginPage("/login")
                                        .successHandler((req, res, auth) -> clearAuthenticationAttributes(req))
                                        .failureHandler((req, res, exc) -> res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
                                        .permitAll()
                                        .and()
                                        .logout(logout -> logout
                                                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                                                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                                                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                                                .clearAuthentication(true)
                                                .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK))
                                                .permitAll()
                                        );
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
                );

        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((req, res, exc) -> res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*")); // allow all origins
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")); // allow all HTTP methods
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*")); // allow all headers
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization")); // allow the Authorization header to be exposed
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    private void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fijate que te devuelve `user.getRole().name()` (lo usas en `WebAuthentication`). ¿Puede ser que sea nulo?

Comment: Hice un debug de la aplicación al momento de recibir la petición pero el rol está correcto. El valor es el que debería ("ADMIN"). Sólo he descubierto que en un momento de la cadena de filtros de Spring Security se invoca un metodo llamado "eraseCredentials", que por lo que su nombre indica, elimina las credenciales. No sé porqué lo hace, no sé si es normal que lo haga o es que hay algún tipo de error en el medio que lo lleva a invocar a ese método.